# busybox tab completion in vi mode

Tags: autocomplete, busybox

When I use busybox and switch editing mode to vi via `set -o vi` then tab completion stops working. When I switch back `set -o emacs` then tab completion starts working again.

```
# set -o vi
# ls -l <TAB><TAB>
# set -o emacs
# ls -l <TAB>
.ash_history          .ssh            file2
.bash_history         file1           file3
```

Is it possible to use tab completion in vi mode in busybox?

Comment: BusyBox includes two shells: ash and hush. Do you know which one it is? Do you know which compilation options were used (it makes a difference sometimes, I don't know if there's an option that matters here)?

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. Your question opened my eyes. The shell in my environment is neither ash nor hush. It is actually bash although it is busybox used on that machine. And the `SHELLOPTS` contains a `posix`. It is quite strange that the options `posix` disables tab completion only when the option `vi` is set but that is the different question.

Comment: @ZabojCampula, see [vi editing mode in POSIX mode](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/bash-completion-in-posix-mode/212662#212662)