# How to enable bash completion in vi mode on Synology DSM6

Tags: bash, autocomplete, vi-mode, synology

When I turned on vi mode in bash by setting `set -o vi` suddenly the tab completion was broken, and a literal tab was inserted. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR** Solve by creating `~/.profile` with

```
if [ $0 != -bash ]; then
    exec -l bash
fi
```

---

**Long version:**
After searching for quite a while I found that on DSM6 bash runs in posix mode (verify with `set -o`) and tab completion does not work in vi mode in posix mode ([bash completion in Posix mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/bash-completion-in-posix-mode)). I tried the proposed solution by adding `bind TAB:complete` to my `~/.bashrc` but that didn't work. I also tried to turn off posix mode with `set +o posix` and this worked, but only on the commandline and not when set in `~/.bashrc`.

So I tried figuring out why bash would start in posix mode by default. I discovered that my login shell was set to `/bin/sh` (you can find this in `/etc/passwd`) which is symlinked to `/bin/bash` (verify with `ls -l /bin/sh`).
In the [bash man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) it says that

> If **bash** is invoked with the name **sh**, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of **sh** as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.

so the solution it seems, was changing the login shell to `/bin/bash`. After I did this I couldn't ssh to my synology anymore, reason: `Permission denied, please try again.`
The cause? Apparently, [Synology disallows any other login shells than `ash` or `sh` and they patched and compiled this into the OpenSSH binary](https://serverfault.com/a/470919/178440) (why the &*#$% do they think this is a smart idea?!)

So what to do? The proposed solution is to start a new `bash` session by creating `~/.profile` with

```
if [ $0 != -bash ]; then
    exec -l bash
fi
```

and now setting `set -o vi` in `~/.bashrc` works as expected. Only problem is that the default profile in `/etc/profile` is not read anymore, so you have to set a nice prompt (PS1) yourself in `~/.bashrc`. You can copy a standard ubuntu `~/.bashrc` or you can have a look at the standard PS1 in `/etc.defaults/.bash_profile`.

Comment: By running `exec /bin/bash`, you get a "child" shell instead of a login shell.
You need to add the `-l` switch to `exec` in order to get a login shell.
Also be warned that by doing so your current test will get in an infinite loop. :)
Try something like this instead : `if [ $0 = -bash ]; then exec -l bash; fi`

Comment: of course this should be `[ $0 != -bash ]` instead of `[ $0 = -bash ]` !

Comment: @NicolasMelay Thanks, I hadn't realized that, I changed it to your suggestion!